# Redirects an authenticated user back to the originally requested URL or the default URL in laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I am new at laravel and I want to achieve the following results, let's say a guest gets to the result page after searching for a term and then decides to login, how can I get the user to login and keep the same result page in laravel 
I have the following code 
in the filters.php I have the following:

```
Route::filter('guest', function()
 {
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

then in the user controller I have the following

**the show login function**

```
public function login()
{
    return View::make('users.login');
}
```

**the handle login function** 
    public function handleLogin()
    {
        $data = Input::only(['email', 'password']);

```
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password']])){
        return Redirect::to('/profile');            
    }
    return Redirect::route('login')->withInput();

}
```

right now the default page after login goes to the profile page but I want the user to go back to wherever he was before login.

any help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you looking for

```
return Redirect::back();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, true that it takes back to the url of the result page but I am getting the error of not recognizing the query  that was made if a search is performed

Comment: If your search is using a POST method, so yeah it won't be able to recognize the query because it wasn't save.

Maybe you can used a GET method for your search ?

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 4, you can use `Redirect::guest` and `Redirect::intended` to achieve your target easily.

`Redirect::guest` put the current URL into the session before redirect to the target URL.

`Redirect::intended` check whether there is any URL saved in the session, redirect to that URL or a default location if it does not exist.

In action, your code can be:

```
if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password']])){
    return Redirect::guest('/profile');            
}
```

and after log in

```
if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::intended();
```